# I want to count how many '1's in a flag column and then add 1 on it so I can call out the next possible number

Tags: php, boolean, queue, counter, addition

1. I purposely added a flag column to a table
2. I want to count all rows with '1'(It can count already)
3. Then, I want to add '1' to the value in No.2 so I can echo/callout the next number(I dont know how to do this)
4. I am making a queue management system

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QueueP1 WHERE STATUS = '1'";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   echo "No ".implode($row)."<Br>";
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do calculations with MySQL functionality.

```
$sql = "SELECT (COUNT(1) + 1) AS 'next_number' FROM QueueP1 WHERE STATUS = '1'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "No ".$row['next_number']."<br/>";
```

Use COUNT(1) to free MySQL from counting all columns and speed up query.

Comment: For connection with databases better use class PDO. It's more secure.

Comment: Another issue: How can i code to alter the 'next_number' status to '1'

Comment: @AleksandrBerlin Why would you suggest that? First off, there's no user input involved. Second, PDO is only as effective as any other other api but using a prepared statement, which isn't needed here.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I guess it’s about developing your own habits. PDO is universal tool for working with data. It has many additional options to set up connection you need

Comment: Mr Aleksander.. I have an else statement if the query reaches the last record. So, if its on the no 8 row of an 8 row table - it will not proceed to show no. 9. Can you help how to set my condition statement and where to put it